# Need to subtract some hours from given timestamp in hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql, sql-date-functions

Input: unix_timestamp('01/15/2018 15:26:37', 'mm/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss')

Expected output is 4 hours delay from above utc input time i.e 01/15/2018 11:26:37

I know that there is date_sub function in hive but it is only used to subtract days from the given timestamp. But I need to know if there is a way by which I can subtract hours or minutes or seconds.

I have also tried something like below as EDT timezone is 4 hours behind UTC (but getting wrong output):

```
SELECT to_date(from_UTC_timestamp(unix_timestamp('01/15/2018 15:26:37', 'mm/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss')*1000, 'EST6EDT')) as earliest_date; -- OUTPUT: 2017-12-31 (wrong)
```

So can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works fine.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('01/15/2018 15:26:37', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')-4*3600, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [the answer of @StrongYoung](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53408280/9145106).

I find it very useful to define such long expressions as a macros and place in the initialization file (e.g. `hive -i init-file.hql ...`).

```
hive> create temporary macro sub_hours(dt string, hours int)
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') - 3600 * hours, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
OK
Time taken: 0.005 seconds
hive> select sub_hours("01/01/2019 00:00:00", 5);
OK
12/31/2018 19:00:00
Time taken: 0.439 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Macros are available starting from Hive 0.12.0, further details can be found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/DropMacro) (pay attention to the "bug fixes" section).

Answer (score 0):

E.g. Your current time in your specific timezone - 1 hour:

```
select date_format(
        from_utc_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'Europe/Madrid') - INTERVAL 1 hours,
        'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
     as PREVIOUS_HOUR
```